# Correct way to handle multiple models in Ionic and PouchDB?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, data-modeling, pouchdb

This may be more of a PouchDB question, but is anyone familiar with the correct way to handle multiple models?

Most examples that I have seen, such as [this](http://gonehybrid.com/how-to-use-pouchdb-sqlite-for-local-storage-in-your-ionic-app/) and various to-do app examples assume one model and as such for their list pages do a db.allDocs().

For multiple models, does it make more sense to

- Use one database per model (i.e. new PouchDB('modelname'))
- Have a variable in the document that captures the document 'type'
- Something else entirely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way is to prefix each `_id`, e.g. `employee_1`, `job_2`, etc. Then you can fetch using `allDocs()` with startkey/endkey.

Comment: Gotcha, do you include the prefix as a string in pouchCollate.toIndexableString()?

Comment: Or are you 'put'-ing right away again with the new prefix?

Comment: `pouchCollate.toIndexableString()` works fine (e.g. `toIndexableString(['employee', 1])`), or you can do the string concatenation yourself if you don't have complex data (i.e. non-strings)

Comment: Can you please explain how i can use startkey/endkey to fetch based on the appended prefix. eg. If i want to only get records with the prefix employee. I'm new to pouchdb.